# Routing Error in Ruby on Rails "action: show"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new with RoR and i'm trying to make a master-datail:
User
-Lugar(place)

My Routes.rb

```
  resources :users do
    resources :lugars
  end
```

my controller lugars

```
class LugarsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @lugar = @user.lugars.create(params[:lugar])
    redirect_to account_url
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @lugar = @user.lugars.find(params[:id])
    @lugar.destroy
    redirect_to account_url
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @lugar = @user.lugars.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @lugar = @user.lugars.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @lugar = @user.lugars.all
  end
end
```

And my view

```
....
    <% @user.lugars.each do |lugar| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= lugar.nombre %></td>
        <td><%= lugar.telefono %></td>
        <td><%= lugar.direccion %></td>
        <td><%= lugar.numero %></td>
        <td><%= lugar.localidad %></td>
        <td><%= lugar.provincia %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Editar",  user_lugar_path %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Eliminar", [lugar.user , lugar], :method => :delete %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
....
```

I'd created and empty file in my lugars view "show.html.erb" but when I enter the page allways get:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lugars"}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `user_lugar_path` without an ID/object, so it doesn't know which individual resource to route to. Since the resource is nested you must pass it the `lugar` itself and the `user` it is nested under:

```
link_to "Editar", user_lugar_path(@user, lugar)
```

You can also simply pass [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) the objects:

```
link_to "Editar", [@user, lugar]
```

You can read more about this in [Rails Guides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects).

Comment: Thanks! routing error dissapears but now when I try to enter the link I have: Template is missing

Missing template lugars/show, application/show with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.

Comment: @AgustinSeifert You need a `app/views/lugars/show.html.erb` file.

Comment: Oh I see. My views folder was named "lugar" instead "lugars" Thank you very much!!!